# linq query exception when navigation empty

Tags: telerik-open-access

for a fitness center management software i have 3 tables :
customers, subscriptions, sessions

- there is 1 to many relationship between **customers** and **subscriptions** tables
- there is 1 to many relationship between **subscriptions** and **sessions** tables

now i want to show a list of customers with their sessions count :
this query gave me an exception

```
var query = _context.CUSTOMERs.Select(c => new
{
adh = c,
cnt =      c.SUBSCRIPTIONs.OrderByDescending(s=>s.SUB_START_DATE).FirstOrDefault().SESSIONs.Count
});
```

my guess is beacause some of the cusomers don't have subscriptions yet  .

secondly : What the Defaultifempty operator and can it help me in this situation
thanks for your help and good day

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectMany to get counts

```
_context.CUSTOMERs.Select(c=> new { Customer = c, 
          SessionCount = c.SelectMany(c=>c.SUBSCRIPTIONs)
                          .SelectMany(su=>su.SESSIONs).Distinct().Count()})
```

That will give you all the sessions as it seems to be what you want

Comment: not exactly, let's say that i want to show customers informations in a table, so i may have a datagrid with columns, firstname, lastname, and sessions.count